# How to access IoT Hub Device Message.ContentEncoding in Azure Function IoTHubTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

My client application running on .NET Core uses Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.20.3 to send Messages to IoT Hub.
The client sets the property "ContentEncoding" in the Message class.

On the cloud side, i want to process the messages in an Azure Function v2 using IoTHubTrigger. 
When messages are sent i receive an array of EventData messages. I was expecting the ContentEncoding value to be available in the System Properties but to my confusion it isn't available anywhere in the EventData class.

Custom Properties are transmitted without a problem.

Is this a known problem and i should transmit content encoding in a custom property as well?

Edit: Same happens with ContentType.